# ¿Cómo acumular valores de una consulta ajax en una variable por cada id de producto?

Tags: laravel, ajax, blade

Tengo varios productos, y esos productos tienen diferentes tarifas según la edad. Necesito consultar en cada producto las tarifas, enviando a través de Ajax el id del producto a consultar y las edades, dichas edades las estoy enviando en un ciclo For una por una, y las respuestas las obtengo correctamente. Por ejemplo, si tengo 3 productos con id 1, 2 y 3, y el array de edades contiene [23,34,56,65], entonces en el primer For envío los id de producto y en el segundo For las edades, para que se genere la consulta de la tarifa de cada edad por cada producto, la idea es ir sumando las respuestas de la tarifa de cada edad en una variable y luego mostrar en la vista el Total en cada producto. El problema que tengo es que los totales de acumulan para cada id, es decir, el total para el producto con id 1 es 280, y lo muestra correctamente en la vista, pero, el total para el producto con id 2 es 150, pero en la vista muestra 430, la suma del total 1 y el total 2, y el total para el producto con id 3 es 100, pero en la vista muestra 530. Agradezco su ayuda para indicarme cómo puedo acumular y mostrar correctamente los resultados, a continuación el código:

**Consulta Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cantidad_dias = {{$request->days}};
    var age = [{{implode(",",$request->age)}}];
    var ids = {{$ids}};
    for(var x = 0; x < ids.length; x++){
        var total = 0;
        var url = "{{route('tarifa', ['id' => 'temp'])}}";
        url = url.replace('temp', ids[x]);
        for(var i = 0; i < age.length; i++){
            console.log(ids[x]);
            console.log(age[i]);
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                type:"GET",
                url:url,
                data:{cantidad_dias:cantidad_dias,age:age[i]},
                datatype:"json",
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response.id,response.edad,response.total);
                    total += response.total;
                    $("#prod_"+response.id).html('$' + new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(total));
                },
                error:function(){
                    $("#nota").html("Algo salio mal, por favor inténtalo de nuevo.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: cambia `total +=` por `total =`

Comment: Hola John, ya lo hice, pero de esta forma no me suma los resultados de todas las tarifas de un mismo producto, solo muestra la primer tarifa de cada producto.